# How to allow the user to override a subset of the configuration using their own yaml file?

Tags: fb-hydra

Let's say I have this basic app:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore


@dataclass
class MyAppConfig:
    req_int: int
    opt_str: str = "Default String"
    opt_float: float = 3.14


cs = ConfigStore.instance()
# Registering the Config class with the name 'config'.
cs.store(name="base_config", node=MyAppConfig)


@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_name="base_config", config_path="conf")
def my_app(cfg: MyAppConfig) -> None:
    print(cfg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```

Is it possible for the user to be able to call my app like this:

```bash
python my_app.py req_int=42 --config="~/path/to/user-defined-config.yaml"
```

And `user-defined-config.yaml` would contain only this:

```yaml
opt_str: User Config String
```

The output should look like this:

```
{'req_int': 42, 'opt_str': 'User Config String', 'opt_float': 3.14, 'config': 'hydra-user-conf'}
```

The closest I got to that is:
`user-defined-config.yaml`

```yaml
defaults:
  - base_config
  - _self_

opt_str: User Config String
```

And the invocation:

```bash
python hydra/app.py req_int=42 --config-path='~/path/to' --config-name="hydra-user-conf"
```

But this way the user (who I don't want to require to be familiar with hydra) has to specify the path to their config file via two cli arguments and also include the `defaults` section in their config, which would be redundant boilerplate to them if they have to always include it in all of their configuration files.

Is this the closest I can get with hydra to the desired interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to pre-configure the [config searchpath](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/search_path/#overriding-hydrasearchpath-config) in the primary config. Adding something like ~/.my_app/ to your config searchpath (thus potentially eliminating the need for `--config-path|-cp`.

In yaml it would look like:

```yaml
hydra:
  searchpath:
    - file://${oc.env:HOME}/.my_app
```

Another thing to consider is having the app generating an initial config for the user on demand. I took this approach with [Configen](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/tree/main/tools/configen#setup).

In general, the current patterns are not amazing and maybe there is room for some improvements in Hydra to make this more ergonomic (You can open a [discussion](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/discussions) about it).